# How to delete a row from database using javafx?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Well, I have some problems trying to create a "delete" function. I want to delete the row that I'm selecting.

(Database: PostgreSQL)

I tried like this firstly but i want to delete the selected row not the one with the specified id

```
public void delete(ActionEvent event) {
    String sql = "DELETE FROM items WHERE id = ?";

    try (Connection conn = dc.connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        int id = 3;
        pstmt.setInt(1, id);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Picture:
[I want to delete all the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJhXp.png)

Comment: Show what you have attempted.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I tried only to delete using this firstly but i want to delete the row that i select not the rows that are with id 3;            
     public void delete(ActionEvent event) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM items WHERE id = ?";

        try (Connection conn = dc.connect();
             PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

             int id=3;
             pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
     }

Comment: Not pictures or images of code which we cannot fix (and many will not even look at), show the actual code posted in your answer with minimum viable code that demonstrates your issue. Edit your question to add it not just add as a comment. If you do not post in the question people will see that first and not read comments in many cases.

Comment: Ok. just modified

Comment: How do you get the `id` of the selected row? i.e. you set it `int id = 3;` but you need to pass the id in not hard code it.  Generally speaking "id" would not be a duplicate in a database table generically but your design is your design.